# Second order DE with unknown right side of the equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following equation:

$$ A''+\omega^2 A=\frac{d}{dx}J(x) $$

where $J(x)$  is an unknown function, $A(x,y)$ and prime means $\frac{d}{dy}$.

But still, this equation must be solved in the following way (as far as I understand):

the first step is to solve the homogeneous equation of the form:

$$ A''+\omega^2 A=0 $$

which is trivial:

$$A = C_1e^{i\omega_0y} + C_2e^{-i\omega_0y} $$

the next step is to assume:

$$A = C_1(x)e^{i\omega_0y} + C_2(x)e^{-i\omega_0y} $$

so that $C_1(x)$ and $C_2(x)$ are the functions of $x$.

The next step is to try to solve it by the method of variation of constants.

And by doing this I am getting nonsense..

$$A' = i\omega_0C_1(x)e^{i\omega_0y} - i\omega_0C_2(x)e^{-i\omega_0y} $$ than

$$A'' = \omega_0^2C_1(x)e^{i\omega_0y} - \omega_0^2C_2(x)e^{-i\omega_0y} $$

and then substitung in the first initial equation I am getting:

$$ \frac{d}{dx}J(x)=0 $$

which is simply wrong...

I expect to find some dependancy of  $C_1(x)$ and $C_2(x)$ on  $J(x)$ .

But to me, it looks like I am doing it the right way, but of course, I am missing something..

Could someone please provide clarification and help me to find my mistake in the method?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does $A'$ mean $\frac{dA}{dy}$ or $\frac{\partial A}{\partial y}$

Comment: it means d/dy, ordinary DE

Answer (score 0):

Solving it as a PDE we have

$$
A(x,y) = c_1(x) \sin (\omega  y)+c_2(x) \cos (\omega  y)+\frac{u'(x)}{\omega ^2}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, but could you please provide your answer with more details ?